# ParseInt with letters

Tags: java, android, json

I have a database from an url and i have data, which is hosted there.

```
JSONObject jsonobject = jarray.getJSONObject((int)Long.parseLong(id)); // parseLong
id = epa.getText().toString(); // function used for id
---
Edittext epa; // Edittext used
```

A few years back i made an app, with it i can search a server database which can find products when an id was entered in the edittbox. But now the company which adapted this technology, adapted product codes from another associate. So now the id i need to 'get' or 'search' or 'find', needs to contain letters,  dashes and dots.

I have been searching for a few weeks now, does anyone have a way to parse String instead of Int?

Comment: Parsing String into what ?

Comment: I have script which allows me to parse json, have strings setup to be able to receive the Strings the getJSONObject, allows to receive. So when someone entered 1, id 1 was returned in textviews,  with corresponding info.. Now the product numbers have changed, now they contain letters.. Is there a way for me to be able to search for string or charsequence to still be able to return the id and corresponding info?

Comment: @Mena This shows an error, getJSONObject(int) cannot be applied to(java.lang.String)

Comment: @derdalderen33213 my bad. The `getJSONObject` method of `JSONArray` takes an `int` as the index of your object in the array. If your objects are ordered and the id is the index (bad design here), then the id can't be changed to a `String` without seriously breaking stuff. You should probably have your `JSONObject` have an `id` property of type `String`, then iterate and match the right one by `id`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have edit text , he will read any input as string

```
Edittext epa;
```

you want convert it to int

here is the code

```
id = Integer.parseInt(epa.getText().toString());
```

if you want convert your int to long

use this code

```
Long.valueOf(int);
```

last thing call you method with any way you like

```
JSONObject jsonobject = jarray.getJSONObject((int)Long.parseLong(id));
```

i hope this help you